# C:2061 error on identifier vector despite vector is included in my .h file?

Tags: c++

I am having a C2061 error on the private methods on my classifier.h file.  As you can see, I have #include vector, and i am using it for a public struct.  Can someone please help me understand what I am overlooking?

```
#ifndef CLASSIFIER_H
#define CLASSIFIER_H

#include "patient_data.h"
#include <QObject>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Classifier : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Classifier(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Classifier();
    void classify(std::vector<patient_data>data, patient_data i);


    struct CreateSDTable
    {
        std::vector<int>sum[3];   //element 0 = Tumor, element 1 = Stage, element 2 = Adjuvant
        std::vector<long>mean[3];
        std::vector<long>error[3];
        std::vector<long>SDL[3];
        std::vector<long>SD[3];
    };

    CreateSDTable CurrentvsNeutropenic;
    CreateSDTable CurrentvsNonNeutropenic;


private:

    std::vector<int> calculatesums(vector<patient_data> data, patient_data i, Neutropenic n);
    std::vector<long> calculatemean(vector<int>validpatients, CreateSDTable Neut, CreateSDTable NonNeut);
    std::vector<long>calculateerror(patient_data d, vector<int>m);
    std::vector<long>calculatSDL(int nvp, CreateSDTable CVN, CreateSDTable CVsNN);
    int NumofValidPatients(patient_data x);
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? And *what* does complete error log say?

Comment: C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Neutropenia_Application\classifier.h:33: error: C2061: syntax error : identifier 'vector'

Comment: Do you really want *arrays* of vectors?

Comment: you probably need std::vector instead of just vector in calculatesums etc - also you might want to pass patient_data vactor by const reference?

Comment: I want to return A vector for each method